# Changing css depending on SQL value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm new to both php and jquery, and i'm trying to create a webpage which shows players and it's status based on data from my Mysql server.

The base code works, although the code scraped together from multiple youtube tutorials :)

I would like to change the opacity of a player's row when it's status is, or becomes 0 (dead).

This is the code i have so far :

pagetest.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>pagetest</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="show">
  <tr>
    <td>player</td>
    <td>status</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        $('#show').load('test.php')
      }, 3000);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php

  $conn = mysqli_connect("myserver", "myuser", "mypass", "mydb");
  if ($conn-> connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed:". $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $sql = "SELECT player, status FROM mytable";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "<tr><td>" . $row["player"] . "</td><td>" . $row["status"] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
  }
  else {
    echo "No game data available";
  }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason for using jQuery with it? If no, then you can use this code:

```
<body>
 <?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");
  if ($conn-> connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed:". $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $sql = "SELECT player, status FROM mytable";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
   echo '<table id="show">
        <tr>
          <td>player</td>
          <td>status</td>
        </tr>';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $status = $row["status"];
  $player = $row["player"];
  echo "<tr style='" . ($status == 0 ? 'opacity: 0;' : '') . "'><td>" . $player . "</td><td>" . $status . "</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
 }
else {
  echo "No game data available";
}
  ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
echo '<tr class="player-status-'.$row["status"].'"><td>'. $row["player"] .'</td><td>' . $row["status"] . '</td></tr>';
```

Add a class to your line `tr` based in the `$row["status"]` so rendered you'll have something like this: `<tr class="player-status-0"><td>cristiano ronaldo</td><td>0</td></tr>`

this way you can create a style to this class with css

```
.player-status-0 {
  opacity: 
}
```

By the way, have thought about using ajax and return a json with the data?